# How to pass URL param from Angular to NodeJS(Express) to use it in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a table and click on a record(row) opens a new view with new URL with rowID from clicked record (localhost/**1**).
I want to pass this rowID param from URL to Express and use it in SQL query.
Can I do it with making a request to my server like this

```
$http.post('/load/:rowID',{'ROW_ID': rowID})
       .success(function(response){
            //handle OK response
        })
       .error(function(response){
            //habndle error
        })
```

and use rowID in Express to search for it in database:

```
app.get('/load', function(req, res) {

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROW_ID = rowID';
connection.query(queryString, function (error, results) {
    if(error) {
        throw error;
    }
    else {
        // We got a result: render it
        res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

});

and at the end get data with certain rowID to show it on the frontend?

```
$http.get('http://localhost/load').success(function (data) {
            data.forEach( function( row, index ) {
                $scope.push(data);
            });
        })
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I'm not sure is that the right way to achieve this functionality. Also, this code doesn't work and I ask for help. Thank you.